# Unable to install symfony/console:3.2 via composer and flex

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4, semantic-versioning

I have a Symfony 4 project and am trying to install [this](https://github.com/oasmobile/php-dynamodb-odm) package for working with AWS DynamoDB.

When I run `composer require oasis/dynamodb-odm` I get an error saying `oasis/dynamodb-odm v0.5.3 requires symfony/console ^3.2 -> no matching package found`. Attempting to run `composer require symfony/console:^3.2` also results in the "Could not find package..." error.

As I am using Symfony 4, composer commands are intercepted by Symfony Flex and some extra stuff happens. Interestingly, there is a Flex recipe for symfony/console:3.3 but not 3.2 which I imagine might be the problem.

My understanding of the caret is that it should allow minor version bumps, so I wonder why console v3.3 is not installed instead.

I would like to use this package, and there aren't many DynamoDB PHP offerings out there, so how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you checkout the composer.json file of the package, you can see the following

```
"require"     : {
        "php"                 : ">=5.6",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.4",
        "oasis/aws-wrappers"  : "^2.10",
        "oasis/logging"       : "^1.0",
        "doctrine/common"     : "^2.7",
        "symfony/console"     : "^3.2",
        "symfony/finder"      : "^3.2"
    },
```

meaning it is compatible with symfony3 only.

Probably you can fork the repo and try changing the version numbers and test it. If it works you can install it.

Comment: Right okay. So composer can't install `symfony/console:3.3` because I am already using `symfony/console:4.3`, which makes sense